# Как вместить заголовок в showerror полностью?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
showerror(message=text,title='bla-bla-bla,just text')
```

В итоге титл не помещается в заголовок,пишет `bla-bla-bla,ju...`

В шаблоне функции `showerror` нет аргумента,который управлял бы шириной заголовка или самого окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем вопросе очень мало деталей. Предположу, что метод `showerror` относится к `tkinter`. Действительно нет управления шириной. Но оно и не нужно. Чем больше текст описания, тем шире окно, а следовательно и место для заголовка.

Мне не удалось получить заголовок `bla-bla-bla,ju...` даже с пустым сообщением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несколько слов описания создадут много места для заголовка

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showerror("the long long long title", "Some text in order to describe occurred error.")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]